# Summing a dataframe with lapply

Tags: r

Here I'm attempting to sum the columns for c1,c2,c3 and add total to a new column in res dataframe :

```
res <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2), "c1" = c(1,2), "c2" = c(3,4), "c3" = c(5,6))
res_subset <- data.frame(res$c1 , res$c2 , res$c3)
tr <- t(res_subset)
s1 <- lapply(tr , function(x){
  sum(x)  
})
```

s1 contains :

```
s1
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 5

[[4]]
[1] 2

[[5]]
[1] 4

[[6]]
[1] 6
```

I take the transpose of the columns to be summed ( `tr <- t(res_subset)` ) as lapply executes function against each column but I'm attempting to execute function against row.

Is there an issue with how I take transpose as this appears to work for simpler example :

```
res1 <- data.frame("c1" = c(1,2), "c2" = c(3,4), "c3" = c(5,6))
lapply(res1 , function(x){
  sum(x)  
})
```

returns :

```
$c1
[1] 3

$c2
[1] 7

$c3
[1] 11
```

Comment: Trying to understand. Why not straightforward `res$c1 + res$c2 + res$c3
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood right what you need, just use rowSums() function.

```
res$sum <- rowSums(res[,2:4])
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `sum` returns a scalar, which is not what you want here.  Instead, `col1 + col2 + ...` gives the desired result.  So you can use `Reduce` in combination with `+`:

```
res$sum <- Reduce(`+`, res[, c('c1','c2','c3')])
```

The `+` operator must be quoted with backticks, since we are using it as a function. (I think quoting with normal quotation marks is OK too.)

`rowSums` also works, but my understanding is that it will create an intermediate matrix, which is not efficient.